# Automate command execution on switch using Plink

Tags: ssh, batch-file, putty, plink

Periodically my IT team and I need to turn off the WiFi to everyone in the workplace for maintenance. Currently we log into the switch using PuTTY and enter the commands to shut off the WiFi, this takes a little bit of time, not a whole lot but I wanted to simplify these steps for any new guys that come work for us. I wanted to make a batch file so it's a 1 click and done thing. I've done my google searches but all I have been able to do so far is use a batch file to putty into and log into the switch. Trying the `-m` command with a `commands.txt` has been my current issue. What I have so far is this.

```
putty.exe -ssh [user@switch] -pw [password] -m commands.txt
```

This is what I have in my `commands.txt`:

```
config t
int fa 2/0/1
shut
int fa 2/0/2
shut
end
```

This however does not shut down the WiFi. Thank you for your assistance.

P.S. I tried `plink.exe` as well with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one of the following two problems (or both):

- The SSH implementation of many devices (notably Cisco switches, but also others) do not support executing multiple command/lines, when using SSH "exec" channel (which is behind the PuTTY `-m` switch).
- Even if multiple commands are supported, those must be top-level commands. You cannot execute a shell or another interactive command (like your `config`) in the first line and use the other lines to provide its subcommands.

For both problems, the solution is to use input redirection, which has the same effect, as if you have typed the commands/lines one-by-one:

```
(
    echo config t
    echo int fa 2/0/1
    echo shut
    echo int fa 2/0/2
    echo shut
    echo end
) | plink -ssh [user@switch] -pw [password]
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much for the help. This will make this job SO much faster and easier to complete.